# How do I combine numbers in array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am not trying to add the arrays like all the other questions. This is what I want to do:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [4,5,6]
var outPut = [14,25,36]
```

As you can see I want to combine the indexes. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the two collections, and map the tuple elements multiplying the first element by 10 and adding the second. Of course this assumes your collection of integers are limited to a single digit:

```
let outPut = zip(a,b).map{ $0 * 10 + $1 }  // [14,25,36]
```

If your collection elements are not limited to a single digit you can multiply the first element by 10 powered by the number of digits of the second collection (this considers that all integers are not negative:

```
var a = [12,25,37]
var b = [34,567,6443]
let outPut = zip(a,b).map{ $0 * Int(pow(Double(10),Double(String($1).count))) + $1 }  // [1234, 25567, 376443]
```